# Outlook email search crashes

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

i am working on a code that get's a list and checks if the items is in emails subjects, i am trying to go through all the emails to compare to the list but the program crashes after 190 emails or so (there are 289 emails in the folder)

I searched online for solutions for this problem and nothing worked for me

```
oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        // Get the MAPI namespace.
        oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        // Log on by using the default profile or existing session (no dialog box).
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

        // Alternate logon method that uses a specific profile name.
        // TODO: If you use this logon method, specify the correct profile name
        // and comment the previous Logon line.
        //oNS.Logon("profilename",Missing.Value,false,true);

        //Get the Inbox folder.
        oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        //Get the Items collection in the Inbox folder.
        oItems = oInbox.Items;
        MessageBox.Show(oItems.Count+"");
        oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetLast();
public void SearchEmail()
        {
            if (counter<oItems.Count)
            {
                try
                {
                    string s;

                    if (oMsg != null)
                    {
                        s = oMsg.Subject;



                        for (int i = 0; i < allTickets.Count; i++)
                        {
                            label2.Text = oMsg.Subject;
                            string ticketID = allTickets[i].ToString();
                            if (s.Contains(ticketID) && oMsg.UnRead)
                            {
                                unreadTickets.Add(ticketID);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                        oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetPrevious();

                        counter++;
                        button2.Text = counter + "";




                }

                //Error handler.
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                     //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

the catch exception gives me this:

unable to cast com object of type 'system.__comobject' to interface type 'microsoft.office.interop.outlook

and afterward i am getting this error:

nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Welcome To SO, you should also post the error message(s) you got in your question, then the others can understand the problem better and help you.

Comment: Are you sure all 237 are mail items? where is omsg defined? please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for trying to help! i tried to make the code more readable and understandable please check it out, @BugFinder i copied all of the inbox messages to excel to see how many messages are there and it is the correct number

Comment: Ok exactly which line says null?

Comment: oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetPrevious();                                                           if (s.Contains(ticketID) && oMsg.UnRead)
those are the lines that gives errors @BugFinder

Comment: then it really sounds like its not a mail item

Comment: ok so is there a way to ignore it and continue to the next one?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Inbox can contain items other than `MailItem`, such as `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem`. That would explain the cast error. You need to treat items as a generic object and read the `Class` property (exposed by all OOM objects) using reflection - if it is 43 (`olMailItem`), you can cast it to `MailItem`. Or you can use the "as" operator and check for null.

Also keep in mind that the Items collection is not sorted in any particular order unless you first call `Items.Sort` and specify a sort order; otheriwise what you get from `Items.GetLast` is undetermined.